# scultpure changes every time I try to paint

Tags: sculpting, texture-painting, vertex-paint, vertex-paint-mode

so I am new to blender and I have been trying for days to get vertex paint to work on my sculpted object. Ive followed multiple tutorials but it just wont show up.
UPDATE:so now I am able to draw on my figure but I edited my character more in sculpt mode but when I go back to vertex paint mode the edits get undone and it reverts back to the old character? But then its back to the new character when I go into sculpt mode again
I am also using blender 2.931
thank you

here is my file sorry I dont know how to upload it properly
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QP-lvnOZG2e6pbGRKcq46lyGpzp6ZuXC/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you please share your file as well?

Comment: Don't update the question with a totally different content once your first question was cleared up, it creates a mess since it's not clear to other readers what were you asking from the beginning and what other people were answering to. Ask different questions instead

Comment: oh ok sorry about that

Answer (score 2):

I can see that you have the faces in the upper right corner enabled:
[image: faces enabled]

This works kind of as a mask.
You can disable it.

If you want to use a mask, then

- switch to Edit mode
- select the faces that should be affected by the paint brush
- switch back to Vertex Paint
- now only the selected faces should be paintable

Probably you have selected none of the faces and therefore you can't paint anything.

Comment: Yup. In this mode if faces aren't highlighted, you can't paint on them

Comment: Thank you so much I would have never though that was the problem but it works now thank you

Comment: One more thing, I edited my character more in sculpt mode but when I go back to vertex paint mode the edits get undone and it reverts back to the old character? But then its back to the new character when I go into sculpt mode again

Comment: Hmm, that behaviour sounds really strange. Do you have any modifiers active for your model?

Comment: Im not sure how to check that sorry, I uploaded my file if thats any help

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your second question:

[image: Modifier Tab]

In the properties window in the modifier tab I found the Multires modifier. I never worked with that before, but as I can see there is a different value for "level viewport" and "sculpt".

[image: level]

Set the "level viewport" to the same value as "sculpt" and then you should see no difference any more when you switch between these modes.

Comment: this worked thank you so much for your help I appreciate it!

Comment: Actually there is one more thing im sorry, the object still reverts back to its old form when I go into edit mode. And when I go into object mode its fine, it shows the new version, but then when I edit the object in object mode and go to vertext paint it goes back to the version before I edited it in object mode

Comment: I was trying to reduce the amount of vertexes in object mode and I had to select the object for that but when I am back in sculpt mode I guess the object is not selected?

Comment: Some modifiers don't show up in the edit mode, because usually you want to edit the original mesh. However a lot of modifier have the option to be displayed in the edit mode - this one doesn't have this option. I you want to see the new version in the edit mode you could apply the modifier, but then the window with the settings(first screenshot) disappears.